# Add to favourites and migrate - gets stuck at favourites at the first site?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bookmarks, migrated-questions

### "Bug" description

After

1. I added a question to favourites and
2. it was migrated to another stackexchange site,

it stays in the favourites list in the *original site* - the site it was originally asked at.

Clicking the star at the left of the question only affects the favourites listing at the target site (where it's currently listed).

I want to remove the question from all favourites lists entirely, but nothing I try helps to remove it from the original site favourites listing.

Is this a bug?

### Steps to reproduce

1) add a question to favourites

2) migrate it from `SO` to `meta.SO`

Expected result:

the question appears in `meta.SO` favourites listing and disappears from `SO` favourites listing

Actual result:

the question stays at `SO` favourites listing

Notes:

I should be able to remove the question from favourites if I want to.

### In a nutshell: not a bug (per discussion and answer below)

The question can be removed from the favourites listing itself. Just unstar it at the left of the list item.

Comment: Stupid question, but... which site did you remove it from favourites on? The original or the one it got migrated to?

Comment: Sorry @Anna Lear, I really messed it up. Updated description now.

Comment: I can't follow...favorites are per-site (*never* cross-site), and aren't affected by migrations, what's the issue exactly?  Please explain in detail what you mean by "Clicking the star at the left of the question only affects the favourites listing at the target site"

Comment: @gry - That's the expected behavior, you favorited the question *on that site*, the fact that the post there is now just a stub for the migration is unrelated to favorites and their behavior...that's how it's supposed to work, we don't do anything across sites here.

Comment: @NickCraver Stubs are auto removed after 30 days or so, which will result in <10k users being blocked out of their favorites. Perhaps you could leave the link there and either note that it has been migrated or auto migrate upon clicking?

Comment: @gry - You can still remove it from your favorites list on the source site, just click the star on the favorites list in your profile.

Comment: @yoda - It's really non-trivial to implement that...in any case that's a separate [feature-request], and this post still isn't a bug, it's intended behavior.  No one's arguing favorites can't be better, there's just a fundamental failure in favorites as they are vs. the dichotomy of how the user base wants them to be (subscription vs. bookmark behavior).  Given that, we're reluctant to make major changes or improvements to them without having a clear direction of where they're going.

Comment: @NickCraver I agree this isn't a bug. Was just throwing out an idea. Thanks for the info.

Comment: "You can still remove it from your favorites list on the source site, just click the star on the favorites list in your profile. – Nick Craver" @Nick, please post this as a reply and I'll mark that it solved the problem. As it did.

Comment: @gry - It's already in the answer below, I'd accept that one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a question is migrated, it actually gets duplicated to the new site. <strike>That may/may not include duplicating your "favorite" selection on it. You can remove that one, if so.</strike>

It does make it somewhat more difficult to remove it from favorites on the originally posted site, though; when you click most links to the migrated question, you are forwarded to its new location at the new site...

Once there, though; look for where it is noted that the question was migrated from XYZ. There is a link that will send you back to the originally posted question, on the "old" site. You can unclick it as  a favorite there.

---

As [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone) notes below in a comment, you can also unclick the favorite star from your list of favorites on your profile.

Comment: Note that you can unclick the favourite star from your profile as well.

Comment: @TimStone Good point! Added to the answer, too.

Comment: are you sure about this? (or has it changed?) we just had a question migrated from SO to dba and the 'favorite' selections did not come over with it

Comment: @JackDouglas Actually I'm not sure that the Fave is duplicated to the destination site; The wording of the question made me think it was, but I see that's not what was meant, so I've stricken the relevant language.